# Регулярное выражение - поиск подстроки в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
(test:1, test2:2 ,test3:3,test4:4) Text text text
```

Нужно получить объект с помощью регулярного выражения (т.е. проверять наличие вхождения такого формата данных в строке, чтобы потом из него циклом генерить объект):

```
{
    "test": 1,
    "test2": 2,
    "test3": 3,
    "test4": 4
}
```

Comment: а на каком языке?

Comment: Изначально - js, но мне требуется именно regexp, который сможет прочитать /\(([0-9a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+)\)/, но с бесконечным количеством значений внутри.

Comment: @DanilValov, хотя реализации регулярных выражений в различных ЯП во многом схожи, но все-таки они имеют свои особенности. Лучше указать конкретный язык о котором идет речь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал вам использовать два регулярных выражения:

1. Для выделения подстроки, заключенной в скобки: `/\(([^\)]+)\)/`
2. Для получения ключей-значений из полученной строки: `/([0-9a-z]+)\:([0-9]+)/ig`

Пример JavaScript кода:

```
var parse = function(str) {
    var re1 = /\(([^\)]+)\)/,
        re2 = /([0-9a-z]+)\:([0-9]+)/gi;

    var tmp = str.match(re1);
    if (!tmp) {
        return {};
    }

    var result = {};
    while (match = re2.exec(tmp)) {
        result[match[1]] = match[2];
    }

    return result;
}

var data = parse('(test:1, test2:2 ,test3:3,test4:4) Text text text');
console.dir(data);
```

Comment: А нет ли возможности получения сразу одной регулярной и подстрочки со скобками в строке и всех внутренних значения в match?

Comment: @DanilValov, не думаю, что в общем виде это возможно. А даже если и возможно, ваш код существенно потеряет в читаемости

Answer (score 0):

На javascript одним RegExp для этой грамматики не обойдешься. С помощью одной capture group `()` нельзя захватить сразу несколько групп по шаблону типа `(...)*`. Самое простое - это сделать как предложил `@Dmitriy Simushev`. Либо получить "дерево разбора" и работать уже с ним. Опять же, во входной строке могут быть ошибки (см. пример), и тогда RegExp о них споткнется. В примере из входной строки с помощью RegExp получаются токены, ошибки отбрасываются, а из токенов потом строится объект(ы). Еще вариант - посмотреть [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/), с помощью него можно получить уже конечный объект js.

```
var s = "text test2:2, test2:2 (test:1, test2:2 ,test3:3,test4:4 te:, 4, x:2) " +
        "Text text text test2:2, test2:2 (test:1, test2:2)";

var matches = s.match(/[()]|\w+\s*:\s*\d+(?=\s*[,)])/g);

var objects = [];
for (var i = 0; matches && i < matches.length; ) {
    for (var found = false, o = {}; i < matches.length; i += 1) {
        if (!found) {
            if (matches[i] == "(") {
                found = true;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (matches[i] === ")") {
            break;
        }
        var v = matches[i].split(/\s*:\s*/);
        o[ v[0] ] = v[1];
    }
    if (found) {
        objects.push(o);
    }
}

// matches = [ "test2:2", "(", "test:1", "test2:2", "test3:3", "x:2", ")",
//             "test2:2", "(", "test:1", "test2:2", ")" ]

// objects = [ 0: { test: 1, test2: 2, test3: 3, x: 2 },
//             1: { test: 1, test2: 2 } ]
```